# Checkout API Setup Guide references commands that kill test pages AND do not exist in API

Tags: php, payment, square-connect, square

The following code snippets in the Checkout API Setup Guide at

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/payments/checkout/setup references GetID()

cause the page to fail and are not in the API:

```
$checkoutId = $result->getId();
```

AND

```
$checkoutUrl = $result->getCheckoutPageUrl();
```

In fact, I cannot find reference to those commands anywhere in the technical docs or API reference except on the Setup Guide.

Is the Setup Guide wrong or am I missing something? Is Checkout not fully live? I am not sure why a setup example would not be more supported or reference existing documentation.

Update: In the file provided with the SDK, the file Checkout.md describes that getId() and getCheckoutPageUrl() are getters for protected properties:

> Note: All properties are protected and only accessed via getters and setters.

I get that... they just don't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Square PHP SDK documentation](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/ccb87aa6033110d3d7209c6d9e7748ffc2c1cc21/docs/Model/Checkout.md) on GitHub. Looks like there might be a mistake in that document, I think the code you want is something like:

(they key missing part being a `->getCheckout()`

```
try {
    $result = $checkoutClient->createCheckout(
      $locationId,
      $checkout
    );
    //Save the checkout ID for verifying transactions
    $checkoutId = $result->getCheckout()->getId();
    //Get the checkout URL that opens the checkout page.
    $checkoutUrl = $result->getCheckout()->getCheckoutPageUrl();
    print_r('Complete your transaction: ' + $checkoutUrl);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Exception when calling CheckoutApi->createCheckout: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
}
```

Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: That did it! Thank you Tristan.  Also of note, the line:                             

    print_r('Complete your transaction: ' + $checkoutUrl);

seemed to be concatenated wrong and I believe should use dot (.) format and be:                                

print_r('Complete your transaction: '.$checkoutUrl); I am going to try and file this on 
GitHub but I've never done it before so wish me luck!