# How to confirm you are connecting to the Square API - Problem with Example Script?

Tags: php, square-connect, square

I am going by the PHP Square Connect example here:

[example](https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/php_payment)

It appears to die at line 40:

```
$transactions_api = new \SquareConnect\Api\TransactionsApi();
```

I suspect my setup. Is there a way to check that you are actually communicating with the API properly?

---

More Info: I turned on php error reporting with

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

And now I get:

> Notice: Undefined variable: location in my_path/st.php on line 283

and

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null in my_path/st.php on line 283

Seems like a problem with either the API or the example.  I had a similar problem with the Square Connect Example where it had bad lines:

[Checkout API Setup Guide references commands that kill test pages AND do not exist in API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799860/checkout-api-setup-guide-references-commands-that-kill-test-pages-and-do-not-exi)

Comment: at that point in the code you haven't made a external request yet, that is just setting up the code you'll be using in the future. If it fails there, you probably aren't including the library correctly, but it is really hard to know without knowing any error messages you are getting

Comment: Right! I wish I could get some error messages but not getting anything. I just know that simple echo or print calls below this line DO NOT make it to the screen unless I get rid of it or comment it out.

Comment: I would also look into your error reporting levels, I’m betting you are getting errors but they are just being logged somewhere you can’t see.

Answer (score 0):

OK, looks like this line was the problem:

```
$result = $transactions_api->charge($location->getId(), $request_body);
```

it should be:

```
$result = $transactions_api->charge($location_id, $request_body);
```

So getId is not required. That is how the example listed the line so my bad.  Must have gotten that line from somewhere else on Git.  Honestly, Square has the worst install/examples ever.  Thanks.